# Explicit formula for the inverse of Harish-Chandra map in case $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}_n$

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex reductive Lie algebra (however, we are mainly interested in the case $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}_n$) and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

It is known that the Harish-Chandra map $\gamma\colon Z(U(\mathfrak{g}))\to S(\mathfrak{h})^{\widetilde{W}}$ is an isomorphism. Here $\widetilde{W}$ is the Weyl group "twisted" by $\rho\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ (half-sum of all positive roots) and $\gamma$ is basically the projection of $U(\mathfrak{g})= U(\mathfrak{h})\oplus (\mathfrak{n}^{-}U(\mathfrak{g}) + U(\mathfrak{g})\mathfrak{n}^{+})$ onto $U(\mathfrak{h})\simeq S(\mathfrak{h})$.

**Question.** Is there any known explicit description of the inverse map $\gamma^{-1}$? In other words, how one would construct for a given $\widetilde{W}$-invariant polynomial in $p\in S(\mathfrak{h})$ the corresponding element $\gamma^{-1}(p)$ in the center of the universal enveloping algebra?

Any comments or references would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duflo_isomorphism

Comment: Particular example for the determinant : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92348/capelli-determinant-duflo-determinant-was-it-known

More generally there is bunch of activity to write explicit nice formulas for the center of U(gl_n), such that we can control HC images, related to math. physics.

Comment: Duflo isomorphism is general construction  but it is not that explicit as these formulas

Comment: @AlexanderChervov How do you construct $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant polynomial on $\mathfrak{g}$ out of a $W$-invariant polynomial on $\mathfrak{h}$?

Comment: @VítTuček both sides are algebras (and linear spaces), so you can do it only on the generators (linear bases) and there are nice generators (linear bases) for each, so  everything is explicit and quite well-known

Comment: PS and the MAIN(!) thing about Duflo isomorphism is  - it is isomorphism of ALGEBRAS(!) - it respects the multiplication on the center of U(g) and S(g)=(h)^W. (Konstsevich proved it for quantization of any Poisson manifold).  Thus working on algebraic generators is enough - e.g. take characteristic polynomial - elementary symmetric functions - Duflo( it) = Cappelli-det - so for generators we are done. (But still there is another option to work on linear bases generators for gl_n - as one prefer). And many other options.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Could you please provide a reference?

Comment: @VítTuček Well... About what part ? The interest to the field re-appeared again in early 90-ies motivated by constructions found by physicists - Yangian in particular. Many works have been done by Molev,Nazarov, Olshanski, Okounkov. See some surveys/books by Molev: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211288 - but it is more general - about Yangians and similar - the paradox insight is that it is more easy to look on classical Lie algebras via the Yangian/related point of view ! Thus exposition kind of not focused on gl_n, but with some experience one can downgrade to gl_n from Yangian without changes

Comment: Concerning the linear basis it itself - we should think about Schur functions - so we can ask what are their appropriate analogues in ZU(gl_n) - that can be found e.g. in https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9602028 Andrei Okounkov , and his related papers at that time. 
Though somewhat digging literature similar results can be found in some unknown paper from 1980-ies.